# TestNG from command prompt "Cannot instantiate class" when firefox driver is added

Tags: selenium, command-line, testng

I started with the simple SampleTest.java:

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class SampleTest {

    String message = "Hello World";
    MessageUtil messageUtil = new MessageUtil(message);
    //FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    @Test
    //@Parameters({"baseUrl", "path", "colRead", "excelSheet", "startRow"})
    public void testPrintMessage() {
        Assert.assertEquals(message, messageUtil.printMessage());
    }
}
```

and MessageUtil.java:

```
public class MessageUtil{

    private String message;

    //Constructor
    //@param message to be printed
    public MessageUtil(String message){
        this.message = message;
    }

    // prints the message
    public String printMessage(){
        System.out.println(message);
        return message;
    }
}
```

that can be executed with the following testng.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Sample test Suite">
    <test name="Sample test">
        <classes>
            <class name="SampleTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

I compiled java, configured classpath and it worked fine: I got Hello, World on command prompt.

I added one line to call FireFox browser, see above commented line:

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); //(I also imported import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;)
```

Now I get the error "**Cannot instantiate class SampleTest**"

In Eclipse everything works fine and opens the Firefox browser. Do I need to call a special Selenium Webdriver jar for Firefox? Several suggestions were to call every Selenium jar separately in classpath and, if this is true, it is very frustrating as I don't know which one does what.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

with

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

For more read the [Selenium Documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/)